# PHPUnit Cannot open file "src/autoload.php"

Tags: php, phpunit

I am following the instruction from https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html. Email.php and EmailTest.php contains the same content as mentioned in the document

Folder Structure:

```
src/
    autoload.php
    Email.php

tests/EmailTest.php
```

autoload.php contains

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});
```

I am running this line from the command line

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/EmailTest
```

I am receiving the following output(includes error)

```
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Cannot open file "src/autoload.php".
```

Comment: `"src/autoload.php".` doens't exists `vendor/autoload.php` maybe?

Comment: I have downloaded the phpunit.phar file manually instead of downloading using composer

Comment: You did not completely read https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html, at least you missed the section on autoloading.

Comment: Also note that PHPUnit 3.7 has not been maintained for years, but that is not relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @Sebastian Bergmann happy to hear from you

Comment: @Sebastian Bergmann  could you please tell me what I missed in autoloading section because I have read so many times but I don't understand please post it as an answer.

Comment: Sugumar, install composer and all your autoloading problems go away. 
btw sebastian, thanks for your awesome software! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `src/` directory and the files within it have the proper permissions. Try adding the execute permission to the file or directory.